# How to create a “slopegraph” in d3.js

Tags: visualization, d3.js

In *The Visual Display of Quantitative Information*, Edward Tufte coined a term “slopegraph” for a very minimal type of chart ([more information](http://charliepark.org/slopegraphs/)). The authoritative example looks like this:

[image: Example of slope graph]

There are at least two implementations of slopegraph in [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) in th wild:

- http://markmarkoh.com/tuftes-slope-graphs-in-svg-using-d3js/
- http://skedasis.com/d3/slopegraph/

I had a shot at a more declarative implementation, and also to preserve a 100% correspondence between values in both columns, but got stuck. As expected, when items with similar or same values appear in the data set, the graphics overlap and the chart is not readable.

The [naïve version](http://data.karmi.cz/d3/life-expectancy-slopegraph/) ([source](https://gist.github.com/2339918) ) uses the `linear` scale for computing horizontal position, while the [attempt to “normalize” the positions](http://data.karmi.cz/d3/life-expectancy-slopegraph-normalized/) ([source](https://gist.github.com/2339918/499ce3758141516e09396674b277ae3e6f140a2b)) uses the `ordinal` scale.

I believe better results can be achieved with the ordinal scale, computing the offset based on coordinates of overlapping items. Should the offset be computed separately for both columns, should it be computed in advance based on data, or on the fly during setting the attributes? How could the codebase be expanded so items with the same values are positioned below each other, other items are adjusted accordingly and the values in both columns stay on the same horizontal position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was toying around with your first example a bit in an attempt to address the issue of jumbled text labels, I'm not sure how useful it will be, but in case it adds to the discussion, I figured I would share..

My first effort was to fade the text surrounding the text labels of a data point that was hovered over, this simply selects text labels that overlap the currently selected label's bounding box, and transitions them to near zero opacity:
http://bl.ocks.org/2554902

I then tried to work on a way to arrange the text labels in a compact way, so that each of them were viewable, I did not finish it's implementation because it seemed to extend the boundaries of the visualization too much (it also currently does not work well when changing the year..), but it might be worthwhile to look towards something like this on slightly less 'compact' data:
http://bl.ocks.org/2554910

Edit: it seems that these do not work as intended in firefox, seems to be an issue with getBBox()..

Comment: Hey - if you add line 64 from my gist below (#1) to your gist, it will make the bl.ocks window bigger.

Comment: Thanks for that Zach, I was curious about how some gists did that, cheers

Answer (score 5):

Well-written question and nice starting code with debugging statements, props!

Didn't get through coding all the things I thought of, but for the sake of discussion at least, here goes. (Coding is easy; coming up with what to code/what this should look like is harder.)

1. A [non-optimized] version that uses the linear scale as a guide, but spaces overlapping entries out by shifting all subsequent entries down. (I guess this effectively just stretches the Y axis; this makes it a very tall image unfortunately. Try comparing closer years, e.g. 2008 and 2009 -- image is not as stretched.)
   http://bl.ocks.org/2547496 ([gist](https://gist.github.com/2547496))
2. The same method applied to the ordinal scale. I prefer the `linear` scale version because the `ordinal` scale version doesn't attempt to convey any absolute information through the slopes; however, this makes for a more compact image. http://bl.ocks.org/2573074 ([gist](https://gist.github.com/2573074))
3. Grouping near values together. (Will implement if there's interest.)

Note that both examples 1 and 2 are imperfect implementations, but you get the idea. If either are what you're looking for, I can fix them up.

Comment: Would love to see your third option. Thanks for coding the first 2!

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share another example from Jefff Clark:

http://neoformix.com/Projects/ObesitySlope/

[image]

He's used Processing but handles a few of the problems above very gracefully (one can argue it's also made a bit simpler with a normalized variable)

1. Using expanding aggregates to simplify the visualization and reduce the initial number of data points.
2. Primarily labeling one side of the slope for each point
3. Hiding labels on close / overlapping points until they get hovered over (at which point, the initial labels disappear temporarily)

Overall, Jeff's done a superb job with this. I think he shows great attention to detail. Would be keen to see a similar example in D3!

Comment: Great visualization indeed!, Tariq

Comment: How does this viz actually make sense though? Slopes are useful for comparing how categories have changed. Here, each line shows the difference between males and females - two different categories.